# RegEx for quantifying and finding a character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

Considering a string with 12 characters, I want to split the string in three groups of four characters and find a character in group 1 and 3.

For example:

```
AAAABBBBAAAA  -> B not found (they are in group 2)
ABAABBBBAAAA  -> B found in the first 4 characters (group 1)
AAAABBBBABAA  -> B found in the last 4 characteres (group 2)
```

I only managed to create group 1 and 3, but I don't know how to find the 'B' on them:

```
(^.{0,4})|(.{0,4}$)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what the actual output looks like after the split has happened?  Also, what programming language are you using, if you are using one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) with an infinite width or a predetermined range are are supported in a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like in for example .NET, Python PyPi regex module or Java you might also use:

```
(?<=^[AB]{0,3})B|B(?=[AB]{0,3}$)
```

[Regex example in C#](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5bAB%5d%7b0%2c3%7d%29B%7cB%28%3f%3d%5bAB%5d%7b0%2c3%7d%24%29&i=BBBBBBBBBBBB)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=^[AB]{0,3})` Assert what is on the left is start of string, 0-3 times A or B
- `B` Match literally
- `|` Or
- `B` Match literally
- `(?=[AB]{0,3}$)` Assert what is on the right is 0-3 times A or B, assert end of string

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to match `B`'s that have 3 or less characters behind them...

```
(?<=^...|^..|^.|^)B
```

or `B`'s that have 3 or less characters after them.

```
B(?=.{0,3}$)
```

So, this should match all `B`'s that satisfy your conditions:

```
(?<=^...|^..|^.|^)B|B(?=.{0,3}$)
```

We are using [a positive lookahead and a positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) here. Those will check your constraints, without being a part of the match. This means that only what you are interested in (the `B`'s) will appear in the match. The reason we don't use the quantifier (e.g.: `.{0,3}`), on the lookbehind is because quantifiers generally don't work on them. This is why we resort to the "brute force" aproach: `^...|^..|^.|^`.

#### [See it live!](https://regex101.com/r/FlsbQF/2)

On many languages, positive lookbehinds aren't available. If this is the case, you can use lookaheads for both assertions:

```
B(?=.{8,11}$)|B(?=.{0,3}$)
```

#### [See it live!](https://regex101.com/r/7RKPUs/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. This finds a 'B' in any group of 4.

Perl version:
`^(?:(?=.{0,3}(B))?....)(?:(?=.{0,3}(B))?....)(?:(?=.{0,3}(B))?....)$`
PCRE version:
`^(?:(?:(?=.{0,3}(B)))?....)(?:(?:(?=.{0,3}(B)))?....)(?:(?:(?=.{0,3}(B)))?....)$`

https://regex101.com/r/yV72s2/1

Explained

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      (?=
           .{0,3} 
           ( B )                         # (1), B in first group of 4
      )?
      . . . . 
 )

 (?:
      (?=
           .{0,3} 
           ( B )                         # (2), B in second group of 4
      )?
      . . . . 
 )

 (?:
      (?=
           .{0,3} 
           ( B )                         # (3), B in third group of 4
      )?
      . . . . 
 )
 $
```

---

If you just want to find out if a 'B' matches in the first or last 4, it would be this

`(?:^(?=.{12}$)(?:(?=.{0,3}?(B))....)|(?<=^.{8})(?:(?=.{0,3}?(B))....)$)`

https://regex101.com/r/wEdTCU/1

Explained

```
 (?:
      ^ 
      (?= .{12} $ )
      (?:
           (?=
                .{0,3}? 
                ( B )                         # (1), B in first group of 4
           )
           . . . . 
      )
   |  
      (?<= ^ .{8} )
      (?:
           (?=
                .{0,3}? 
                ( B )                         # (2), B in third group of 4
           )
           . . . . 
      )
      $ 
 )
```